# Finding unique values subject to a constraint - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find unique values in one column of a matrix subject to the max amount listed in col 2 of the same matrix.

My code is the following:

```
    Testing = find(unique(RAW_DATA_2(:,1))&max(RAW_DATA_2(:,2)))
```

To me it reads find unique items in col 1 of the matrix which are also the max of col 2. Matlab disagrees with me however.

An alternative is to not even use the find function and just return a matrix with just the unique values and the max amount for each unique value which would be preferable. I have attempted to use some code I found here on Stack overflow to do this but am having issues with it since I cannot modify it from "first" to "unique".

```
 I = true(size(RAW_DATA_2,1),1);
 idx = [];
 while any(I)
     idx(end+1) = find(I,1,'first');  %#ok
     I = I & all(~bsxfun(@eq, RAW_DATA_2, RAW_DATA_2(idx(end),:)),2);
 end

 result = RAW_DATA_2(idx,:);
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the procedure you want accomplish. Are the values in column 1 like ID numbers, and you want to find the maximum value in column 2 for each ID number?

Comment: column 1 has dates, column 2 has frequency. so if 3/4/2015 appears twice in column 1, I want to return the row that has the greater frequency in column 2 for that given date.

Comment: Did any of the solutions presented here work for you?  Consider accepting  the one that worked best for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your clarifying comment makes the question a lot more understandable. You should consider adding it to the question itself. Here's some code that may help you

```
a = [0 10; 1 100; 3 175; 4 80; 1 200; 2 400; 3 150; 0 10]; % your raw data
asorted = unique(a, 'rows');  %returns unique rows, sorted by value
```

Note that `asorted` does not contain any duplicate rows and is sorted in the following way:

```
asorted =
 0    10
 1   100
 1   200
 2   150
 2   300
 2   400
 3   150
 3   175
 4    80
```

It is now clear that the lowermost row containing each unique element of column 1 is what we need. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
diffidx = [diff(asorted(:, 1)); 1];  % appending 1 because the last row 
                                     % must always be included
result = asort(diffidx~=0, :)
```

Comment: Clever use of `diff`. This solution is a lot less computationally intensive than mine.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but it might be a bit excessive if you have a lot of unique dates.

```
m = max( bsxfun(@times, A(:,2), bsxfun(@eq,unique(A(:,1))',A(:,1)) ));
answer = [unique(A(:,1)), m']
```

As an example with 4 dates, `1,2,3,4`:

```
 2    65
 2    16
 3    94
 4    25
 3    63
 4    26
 3    50
 4    82
 1    92
 3    16
 1    49
 1   100
 2    62
 1    44
 3    34
```

My output is the following, with the "dates" on the left and their corresponding maxima on the right.

```
 1   100
 2    65
 3    94
 4    82
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems an [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) based solution might also be a good fit here -

```
%// Find unique elements from column-1 and also tag/ID each of its elements
[col1_unq,~,id] = unique(RAW_DATA_2(:,1),'stable');

%// Get the max from second column based on the IDs and then concatenate
%// with unique rows from column-1 for the final output
result = [col1_unq accumarray(id,RAW_DATA_2(:,2),[],@max)]
```

Sample run -

```
RAW_DATA_2 =
   12.5000    5.0000
   12.5000    2.5000
    5.0000   12.5000
   10.0000   10.0000
    7.5000    7.5000
    7.5000   10.0000
   12.5000    7.5000
    5.0000   10.0000
result =
   12.5000    7.5000
    5.0000   12.5000
   10.0000   10.0000
    7.5000   10.0000
```

Comment: I was thinking this problem had `accumarray`-like behaviour, but I didn't realize you could change the function it performed! Nice solution and thanks for teaching me something! :)

Comment: @eigenchris Hey, just saw your profile with a link to my profile! It's awesome!! :)

Comment: Well, being a MATLAB programmer for ~5 years and not knowing most of those functions, my mind was slightly blown when I discovered `bsxfun`, `accumaray`, `permute`, etc.